# Firefox crashes when trying to upload or browse a file

Tags: firefox, apparmor

On some websites (like Facebook), there are buttons to select and upload a file. Clicking on them crashes Firefox.

AppArmor seems to be involved. `dmesg | tail` gives me this:

> [ 2935.306465] audit: type=1400 audit(1688718066.409:80264077):
> apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file"
> profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=25819
> comm="glxtest" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

or this

> [ 2935.753897] audit: type=1400 audit(1688718066.857:80264080):
> apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file"
> profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt"
> pid=25878 comm="vaapitest" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
> fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Installing firefox with `apt` hasn't worked, also when using `apt` with the Mozilla's own PPA.

Comment: On my 2nd laptop, I saw that apparmor received an upgrade. Firefox now works well on both computers.